# Select data of a partition with DolphinDB?

Tags: partition, dolphindb

This is the table I used for querying.

```
dbName = "dfs://trade"
tbName = "trade"
if(existsDatabase(dbName)){
    dropDatabase(dbName)
}
db1 = database(, VALUE, 2020.01.01..2022.01.01)
db2 = database(, HASH, [SYMBOL, 5])
db = database(dbName, COMPO, [db1, db2], , "TSDB")
schemaTable = table(
    array(SYMBOL, 0) as SecurityID,
    array(SYMBOL, 0) as Market,
    array(TIMESTAMP, 0) as TradeTime,
    array(DOUBLE, 0) as TradePrice,
    array(INT, 0) as TradeQty,
    array(DOUBLE, 0) as TradeAmount,
    array(INT, 0) as BuyNum,
    array(INT, 0) as SellNum
)
db.createPartitionedTable(schemaTable, tbName, `TradeTime`SecurityID, {TradeTim:"delta"}, sortColumns=`SecurityID`TradeTime, keepDuplicates=ALL)
```

With TradeTime and SecurityID as the partitioning columns, how can I retrieve data for each stock in a specified partition on a day?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the data of the HASH 1 partition of SecurityID on the date 2020.01.02:

```
select count(*) from loadTable("dfs://trade", "trade") where date(TradeTime)=2020.01.02, partition(SecurityID, 1)
```